# Saving data into multiple tables from one form in CakePHP 2.5.1

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I am new in CakePHP, developing a cloud application using CakePHP 2.5.1 and MySQL. i have following tables:

**`users`**

```
  user_id ,
  people_id(FK- people.people_id),
  username,
  password
```

**`people`**

```
  people_id, 
  manager_id(FK- people.people_id), 
  firsr_name,
  last_name,
```

**`roles`**

```
  role_id ,
  people_id (FK- people.people_id),
  role
```

**`addresses`**

```
  address_id,
  people_id (FK- people.people_id),
  street,
  house no,
  post code,
  city
```

Foreign key `people.manager_id` refers to primary_key `people.people_id`.   The field `roles.role` can hold either `'manager'` or `'customer'`.

Now, in my registration form, there will be following input fields:

```
-username
-password
-first name
-last name
-street
-house no
-post code
-city
-role
```

I have used a User model (User.php), a registration form (add.ctp) and a controller (UsersController.php) to input username and password; and implemented login, logout.

The View **`add.ctp`**:

```
<div class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Registrierung'); ?></legend>

        <?php echo $this->Form->input('username');

              echo $this->Form->input('password');
              echo $this->Form->input('password_confirm', array('label' => 'Confirm Password', 'maxLength' => 255, 'title' => 'Confirm password', 'type'=>'password'));


        );  
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Register')); ?>
</div>
```

is working fine. Now I need to include above input fields in the registration form. This means creating models for each table and defining the associations like `belogsTo`, `hasMany`, etc. in my `User` model, I have defined the following association:

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
            'Person' => array(
                'className' => 'Person',
                'foreignKey' => 'people_id'

            )
    );
}
```

However, it throws the following error:

```
Database Error
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Person.id' in 'on clause'
```

Could anyone tell me how to implement these associations? I could not find any example which matches with my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL error is being caused by the way you have named your primary keys. In CakePHP, primary keys should be named `id`.

If you wish to use a different name (not recommendable), you have to tell CakePHP what name you will be using. This is done declaring the `$primaryKey` property. Example:

```
class Person extends AppModel {

    public $primaryKey = 'people_id';

}
```

However, it's preferable that you rename your primary keys and adhere to CakePHP conventions as much as possible.

Also, by the way CakePHP treats plurals, your `people_id` fields should be renamed to `person_id`.

**EDIT: Adding relationships**

Your relationships could be as follows.

**Your `Person` class:**

```
class Person extends AppModel{

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Manager' => array(
            'className' => 'Person',
            'foreignKey' => 'manager_id',
        ),
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'User',
        'Role',
        'Address',
        'Subordinate' => array(
            'className' => 'Person',
            'foreignKey' => 'manager_id',
        ),
    );
}
```

**Your other classes:**

```
class User extends AppModel{

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Person'
    );
}

class Role extends AppModel{

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Person'
    );
}

class Address extends AppModel{

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Person'
    );
}
```

Remember to change all foreign keys from `people_id` to `person_id`.

---

**Modification in model `Role`**

I think you may want to move field `roles.person_id` to `people.role_id`. IMHO it makes more sense.

Your relationships would change to:

```
class Person extends AppModel{

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Manager' => array(
            'className' => 'Person',
            'foreignKey' => 'manager_id',
        ),
        'Role'
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'User',
        'Address',
        'Subordinate' => array(
            'className' => 'Person',
            'foreignKey' => 'manager_id',
        ),
    );
}
```

and

```
class Role extends AppModel{

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Person'
    );
}
```

See

- Cookbook 2.x: [Model and Database Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions)

Comment: thank you for your reply. i have changed the column name to id. the database error has gone now. but can you tell me how to implement the associations, specially people table ? since it has a foreign key which points to the primary key of the same table.

Comment: of course i will mark. actually, my question has two parts, one for the errors and another one is for implementation of the associations. can you help me for the second part ?

Comment: I've added the relationships. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: thank you so much again ! regarding the roles and people tables, i should inform you my requirements. while registering on the application, the user can be registered as a manager or customer. if manager, he/she can have multiple customers. so, in this scenario, do you think i should move the field roles.person_id to people.role_id ?

Comment: If you don't move it, you would end up repeating the value in `roles.role` every time you added a `Person`. You might as well get rid of the `roles` table and add a `role (VARCHAR(8))` field to table `people`, which would hold either `'manager'`or `'customer'`.

Comment: a manager can have multiple customers (1-to-many relationship). how to map a manager to multiple customer within the same table people ?

Comment: You have everything you need. Whenever a `Customer` is assigned a  `Manager`, set `people.manager_id` to the value of `Manager.id`. CakePHP handles this easily, and no configuration is needed if you rename field `manager_id` to `parent_id`. See [`find('threaded')`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-threaded)

Comment: did you mean whenever a Customer is assigned to a Manager, people.id will be assigned to the people.manager_id ?

Comment: Exactly. But we are using aliases, so we set `People.manager_id = Manager.id` (`Manager` is an alias for table `people`).

Comment: you are right ! i will delete the role table. it will be great if you can give me some links which will be helpful in the implementations.

Comment: Just try to keep your design as simple as possible. It's better to start with a "denormalized" design, and normalize it later where you see room for improvement. There are many excellent books and articles on the subject. E.g. [A Quick-Start Tutorial on Relational Database Design](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/Relational_Database_Design.html). You may also try to post questions asking for help on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i have deleted the roles table. now, trying to save the data into multiple tables using a registration form. the problem is data are saved in users and people tables, but not in the addresses table. moreover, as we discussed above, in case of manager role, people.id should be assigned to people.parent_id. but it is not happening. values are remained null in both manager and customer roles. could you please help ? this is the last question :) thank you so much again !

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly define the primary key in each of the models, but that's make it a whole lot complicated.

I'd recommend you to stick to the conventions. Please change all the primary key fields to "id". That'd probably resolve a bulk of your problems.

Peace! xD